# Unable to resolve "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I was attempting to make a silly little pointless piece of code. However, when I try to run the code I get an "invalid syntax" error. This is the code:

```
import time

name=input("What would your name happen to be?")
print("Hello there,", name,"!")

time.sleep(3)

ohno=input("Would you like your PC to crash? (Yes or No)")
if ohno.lower() == "yes":
    print("* crashes", name,"'s PC *")
    else:
        print("Invalid answer, reload script")

if ohno.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay. Have a nice day,", name)
    else:
        print("Invalid answer, reload script")
```

When the error appears, it doesn't even show where the error is. The syntax seems just fine to me.. or I could just be a complete idiot. Well, if anybody can help me, that would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would be surprised, if the traceback doesn't show you, where the error is. I suggest that you edit your question and post the full error message

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` statements are out of indent, you should fix them:

```
import time

name=input("What would your name happen to be?")
print("Hello there,", name,"!")

time.sleep(3)

ohno=input("Would you like your PC to crash? (Yes or No)")
if ohno.lower() == "yes":
    print("* crashes", name,"'s PC *")
else: # change your indenting over here
    print("Invalid answer, reload script")

if ohno.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay. Have a nice day,", name)
else: # and here
    print("Invalid answer, reload script")
```

Comment: @user9408116 Indents matter in Python, you have too many spaces in your `else` statement

Comment: @user9408116 this may be hard to understand, but here's a screenshot of your code: http://i.cubeupload.com/iNQMZn.png they should be like: http://i.cubeupload.com/BgJHTA.png

 Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to setup a three way branch - one message for "yes", another message for "no", and a different message for any other option. But your code doesn't have the `else` statements in the right place for this. You could set it up like this:

```
import time

name=input("What would your name happen to be?")
print("Hello there,", name,"!")

time.sleep(3)

ohno=input("Would you like your PC to crash? (Yes or No)")
if ohno.lower() == "yes":
    print("* crashes", name,"'s PC *")
elif ohno.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay. Have a nice day,", name)
else:
    print("Invalid answer, reload script")
```

Comment: Thanks :) helped me with the problem I realized after removing the idents before both "else"s where if I change around the capitalization when I get to the part where it asks if I would like my PC to crash and lets say I would put "yEs" and it would respond with the response for "yes" but also print the invalid answer. Again, thank you.